# ExrJs 3. How do I add a new element after the field?

Tags: extjs3

In a series of receiving elements of the dynamic form. After some of these elements, I need to add plug-in.
Ie first went to the field, such as input, and automatically added after a new xtype.
Tried createChild, but for some reason he swears by xtype.

Answer (score 2):

```
var formPanel = new Ext.form.FormPanel({
    title: 'Test Form',
    labelWidth: 120,
    width: 350,
    padding: 10,
    tbar: [{
        text: 'Add Item',
        handler: function () {
            formPanel.add({
                xtype: 'textfield',
                fieldLabel: 'My TextBox'
            });
            formPanel.doLayout();
        }
    }],
    renderTo: 'output'
});
```

Demo here http://ext4all.com/post/extjs-3-how-to-add-a-new-field-dynamically